# Collapse in bootstrap not scrolling back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where there is a big part of text hidden under collapse area. It works, however, after second click (in order to hide content, JavaScript scrolls it down on page not to area where content is hidden.

```
<div class="text_owner col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-pull-4"><?php the_field('letme_introduce'); ?>
<div class="collapse" id="introduce">
<p><?php the_field('letme_introduce_hidden'); ?></p>
</div><a class="role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#introduce" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/excerpt.png" class="pull-right introduce" alt=""></a>
```

Do you have any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<div class="text_owner col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-pull-4"><?php the_field('letme_introduce'); ?>
<div class="collapse" id="introduce">
    <p><?php the_field('letme_introduce_hidden'); ?></p>
</div>
<a class="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#introduce" href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="introduce"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/excerpt.png" class="pull-right introduce" alt=""></a>
```